# $f \in [1,\infty) \to \mathbb R, \, f(x) = \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)}$. Show that $\int_1^x{f(t)dt} \le \frac{x-1}{6}$ for any $x\in[1,\infty)$

Tags: calculus

$f \in [1,\infty) \to \mathbb R, \, f(x) = \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)}$
I need to prove that $\int_1^x{f(t)dt} \le \frac{x-1}{6}$ for any $x\in[1,\infty)$

I don't really understand what is asked of me. I see that the right side can be expressed as $\frac{x}{6} - f(1)$. Other than that what I can say about $f(x)$ is that it is strictly decreasing on its domain and $f(1)=\frac{1}{6} \ge f(x)$.

Can you give me some hints, please?

Comment: Hint : For $ t\geq 1$, $f(t)\leq \frac{1}{6}$

Comment: Radu. $f(x)=\frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)}\le \frac{1}{1(1+1)(1+2)}$ for $x \in [1,\infty)$. Then $\int_{1}^{x}f(x)dx \le \int_{1}^{x}(1/6)dx=(1/6)(x-1)$,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Peter. I am disappointed that I did not see it, I hope it will become easier with practice, though.

Comment: Radu.No worry. You practise these kind of things and you'll become a master :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easier way is the following:

$$\int_1^x f(t)dt\leq \max_{t\in [1,x]}\{f(t)\}(x-1)= \frac{1}{1(1+1)(1+2)}(x-1)=\frac{x-1}{6},$$

where $x-1$ is the length of the interval of integration, and the maximum is at the starting point because $f'(t)<0$ for $t\in[1,x]$.

Comment: I see. This is a result of the mean value theorem, right? I was thinking that it must have something to do with it, because of the $x-1$ on the right hand side and the integral bounds as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the easier way to see this is: you are computing the area under the graph of $f(t)$, if you visualize this in your mind, there exists a rectangular which area cover the previous area. The rectangular has length the interval of the length and high the maximum of the function.